# github - actualizar rama remota que difiere con rama local

Tags: git, github, git-push, git-pull

Tengo la siguiente historia en mis ramas

```
* 328944a (HEAD -> master) UX - fin
| * db97e08 (origin/master) UX
|/  
* 0595e34 fin contacto
* c58b176 contacto html
```

El caso es que quiero actualizar el remoto al commit UX - fin pero al momento de hacer *git push* me dice que haga *git pull*, cosa que hago pero me aparece el siguiente mensaje.

```
sugerencia: tiene ramas divergentes y necesita especificar cómo conciliarlas.
sugerencia: puede hacerlo ejecutando uno de los siguientes comandos en algún momento antes
sugerencia: tu próximo pull
sugerencia: git config pull.rebase false # merge (la estrategia predeterminada)
sugerencia: git config pull.rebase true # rebase
sugerencia: git config pull.ff solo # solo avance rápido
```

Por lo que no sé cual sea la opción correcta, y no quiero perder los cambios de UX - fin, los de las otra rama UX no me interesan, solo quiero actualizar la rama remota con la local. Que ambas apunten a UX - fin

Comment: Entiendo que `git pull` es equivalente a `git fetch` y `git merge`. Supongo que sería cuestión de hacer `git fetch`, resolver los conflictos y una vez hecho, hacer `git merge`.  Entonces ahí sí, pusheas. Si prefieres usa una interfaz gráfica que es más amigable que la línea de comandos. Entre ellos están Github Desktop, Sourcetree y Gitkraken.

Comment: Si estas seguro que los cambios correctos son los de la rama local, y no ves necesario hacer mezcla de lo que hay en remoto, puedes utilizar `git push --force`. De esta manera obligas al remoto a cambiar por lo que tiene tu rama.

Comment: @Mateo `fetch` no es una operación que genere conflictos. Los conflictos podrían aparecer al hacer `git merge`.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que sucede es que las ramas *divergieron*. Por defecto, para git dejarte hacer un push a la rama `origin/master`, la rama que quieres empujar (la local `master`) debe incluir lo que esté en `origin/master`. Como las ramas divergieron, git te dice que busques la forma de incluir los commits que ya están en la rama remota en tu rama local (lo que se hace a través de un pull o un fetch/merge).

En tu caso, al hacer pull (por lo que se puede ver), hay conflictos.... esto es *normal* en cualquier proyecto de desarrollo (diferentes ramas pueden modificar las mismas secciones de código de formas diferentes, git no puede adivinar cómo mezclar el código en este caso y por eso hay conflictos).

Al final de la operacion de merge resultarías con un árbol más o menos así:

```
* xxxxxx la mezcla de ambas ramas (HEAD -> master)
|\
* | 328944a UX - fin
| * db97e08 (origin/master) UX
|/  
* 0595e34 fin contacto
* c58b176 contacto html
```

Y como ya al mezclar tu rama incluiría el commit de la rama que está en el remoto, entonces el push debería ser exitoso... *a menos que* (siempre es posible en DVCSs) la rama remota se haya movido (por ejemplo, otra persona hizo un push a esa rama remota).

Hay situaciones en las que podrías decir algo como "en realidad no me interesa mantener el commit de la rama remota... quiere que la historia y el contenido de la rama remota sea como el de mi rama local" (con lo cual eliminarías de la rama remota el commit db97e08). En ese caso podrías hacer: `git push origin master` (o `git push -f` si ya la rama upstream estaba seteada). En ese caso, git no hace la verificación que indicaba al comenzar mi explicación y pues coloca en la rama remota lo que está en tu local independientemente de si tu rama local ya incluye lo que está en la remota o no.